# Java obfuscation

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

when using proguard, it seems to obfuscate entire name spaces that I am merely including. Can I tell it to only obfuscate my code and not all the libs im using? Some of the libs rely on reflection of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ProGuard, but you should be able to exclude classes, package and more from obfuscation using the ["keep" options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions).

Comment: I want something like the opposite of keep.

Obfuscate only the specified name spaces would be great...

Comment: I'm guessing, but try not telling ProGuard where the ZIP files for the libs are; i.e. removing them from the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Proguard makes a distinction between input JARs and library JARs.  You should specify code that should be obfuscated/shrunk using `injar` and code that should not be modified using `libraryjar`.